# Long-Press spark.components.list Item

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder, flex4.5

Does anyone know if there is any sort of Long-Press gesture (like on Android) in the new version of flex?

I'm looking to make an item in a list editable/delete-able upon long-press, but I'm really hoping I wont have to make my own Long-Press gesture with a timer and whatnot.

If there is none built in, does anyone know of any resources/blog posts about how to make a Long-Press gesture - or, furthermore, how to make an Editable list?

Answer (score 2):

flextras answered it, and I just wanted to follow up with a code sample that seems to work. For now, I have it just do a popup asking if you want to delete the item from the list.

```
        private var deleteAlert:DeleteAlert = new DeleteAlert();
        private  var longPressTimer:Timer = new Timer(1500,1);

        protected function LoadChartView_viewActivateHandler(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void {
            enableClick();
        }
        private function startLongPressMouse(event:MouseEvent):void {   
            startLongPressTimer();
            list.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, endLongPressMouse);
        }
        private function endLongPressMouse(event:MouseEvent):void {
            stopLongPressTimer();
            enableClick();
            list.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, endLongPressMouse);
        }
        private function startLongPress(event:TouchEvent):void {
            startLongPressTimer();
            list.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, endLongPress);
        }
        private function endLongPress(event:TouchEvent):void {
            stopLongPressTimer();
            enableClick();
            list.removeEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, endLongPress);
        }
        private function startLongPressTimer():void {
            longPressTimer.start();
            longPressTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, longPressHandler);
        }
        protected function disableClick():void {
            trace("disable click");
            list.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, regularClickHander);
        }
        public function enableClick():void {
            list.callLater(list.addEventListener, [MouseEvent.CLICK, regularClickHander]);
        }
        public function resetListSelection():void {
            list.selectedIndex = -1;
            list.validateDisplayList();
        }
        private function stopLongPressTimer():void{
            longPressTimer.stop();
            longPressTimer.reset()
        }
        public function longPressHandler(event:TimerEvent):void{
            disableClick();
            stopLongPressTimer();
            deleteAlert.addEventListener(PopUpEvent.CLOSE, popupClosedHandler);
            deleteAlert.open(this, false);
            PopUpManager.centerPopUp(deleteAlert);
        }
        public function popupClosedHandler(event:PopUpEvent):void{
            if (event.commit)data.removeItemAt(list.selectedIndex);
            callLater(resetListSelection);
        }
```

I used both the mouse and touch events for easy testing:

```
<s:List id="list" top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0"
        dataProvider="{data}"
        touchBegin="startLongPress(event)" touchEnd="endLongPress(event)"
        mouseDown="startLongPressMouse(event)" mouseUp="endLongPressMouse(event)">
```

Comment: When I do that, `list.selectedIndex` is -1 or the index of a previous selectedIndex. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like it, based on the [ASdocs for the TouchEvent class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TouchEvent.html#constantSummary):

I'm a bit surprised by that, actually.  You can probably mock something up using the [TOUCH_END](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TouchEvent.html#TOUCH_END) and [TOUCH_BEGIN](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TouchEvent.html#TOUCH_BEGIN) events with a [timer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html).

Comment: I'm not.  Remember that Flex is trying to be mobile os agnostic.  By adding that, you're assuming that your users understand long press which isn't used by all OS'.

Comment: @J_A_X Which mobile OS doesn't support it?  I haven't looked at underlying exposed APIs, but iOS, Android, and Playbook all use the long press on their respective "home screens" for moving icons around.

Comment: yeah, but that's about it. Android has long press everywhere as an 'edit' feature in lists and such.  something that iOS or playbook doesn't do.  Either way, creating new gestures aren't exactly hard.

Comment: That's a good point J_A_X. I was hoping to make the project with more of a native feel, so I would either reuse and modify the code in separate projects or just do some os detection logic. 

I was also considering a mix of the two. Long-press on an item to make that item switch to a different ItemRenderer which would have the "drag-able" icon and a delete button. So, it would look similar to an editable list on iOS - but just for that item. One of the paradigms that iOS definitely makes more use of than Android is direct data manipulation, so I like to avoid menus.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [Gestouch](https://github.com/fljot/Gestouch) (develop branch is more up-to-date)
org.gestouch.gestures.LongPressGesture

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the resource! I'll definitely check it out!