# Recognize a holding/long touch on a list component in Flex Mobile

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, list, mobile

I´am trying to create my own custom list component in a Flex mobile Project which fires an Event when the user touches a listitem and holds the finger down for a given time.
Some kind of "longTouch"-Event like its implemented on native android listitems to edit the entry for example.

I tried to listen for the MOUSE_DOWN Event to start a timer and dispatch an event when the timer finished. But this approach failed because i cant get the listitem that was pressed by the user because the List component updates the "selectedItem"-property only after the user lifts his finger from the list.

thanks in advance

Andre Uschmann

Comment: possible duplicate of [Long-Press spark.components.list Item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527138/long-press-spark-components-list-item)

Comment: Please take a look at this article, the author did a really neat thing to handle capture long-touch event. Hope it helps. http://www.eonflex.com/?p=763

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no longTouch (or longPress) event exposed through the Flash Player Native APIs.

One option is to roll your own using [TOUCH_BEGIN](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TouchEvent.html#TOUCH_BEGIN), [TOUCH_END](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TouchEvent.html#TOUCH_END), and a [timer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html).

Basically:

1. When user starts the touch, start the timer.
2. When the touch_End event fires; check the timer to see how long it has been running using [currentCount](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html#currentCount).  If it is long enough to be considered a "long touch", then dispatch your custom longPress event.  If not; then stop the timer and ignore.

   This could all happen inside the renderer; so you'd know exactly what item was pressed.

I expect this would be more solid than using mouse events, which seem to be inconsistent on touch based devices

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Implementing the "LONG_TOUCH" itself isnt the problem but i dont know how to get the listitem which the user touches when starting the timer.

Comment: Dang, you beat me to it! :) You can also use TouchEvent.TAP to capture tap events.

Comment: See more here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527138/long-press-spark-components-list-item) The problem is when the timer start, there is an eventListener on the MOVE and when you move just a little it stop the timer. And it's not easy on a mobile device to put your finger and not to move (my finger keeps slipping on the screen barely but it move enought to stop my timer)

Comment: @Snote I don't see anything in the other post that references the move.  So, moving your finger a little will fire TOUCH_END?  Interesting.  Have you tried the https://github.com/fljot/Gestouch library?  [By, the way I'm going to vote to close as exact duplicate]

Comment: In **startLongPress** : `list.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, endLongPress);` and in **startLongPressMouse** :  `list.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, endLongPressMouse);`. And remove in **endLongPress** and **endLongPressMouse**

Comment: @Snote I'm not following.  IS that code in the gestouch library?  Or somewhere else?  Just don't end the timer in respond to touch_move / mouse_move events.

Comment: No, that code is for the other topic of this site. I just check the code of the gestouch library, you must move from 25px for the code manage it like a to to avoid accidental offset on touch.

Comment: I solved my problem. Putting all the Eventhandling in every single itemrenderer instead of the List component does the trick. thx alot =)